# Non-starting rails 5.2 app - ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage

Tags: digital-ocean, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have deployed two rails apps to Digital Ocean, Ubuntu 18.04 with Passenger and Nginx.

Both apps were built on rails 5.2.2 with ruby 2.5.1, and the second app has all the same gems at the same versions. While the first app runs fine, the second will not launch.

The last useful line of the Passenger log says:

```
[ E 2020-08-06 22:41:56.6186 30885/T1i age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/html/AppName_Prod/current: The application encountered the following error: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
```

I know this is somethign to do with the master.key file, but that is present and contains the correct key. I'm not using environment vars to store the master keys - they are in the master.key file inside each app's dir structure.

I've read every SO post I could find on this and none have solved my issue.
Any suggestions for getting these two apps (and more) to work on the same droplet?
I'm all out of ideas.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might have the same issue, it was a bit deceptive.
I had tried `rails credentials:edit` and it didn't fix the issue, but I found that the app's containing folder was owned by `user:user`, whereas my other app was owned by `user:root`.
When I changed this, everything started to work.

I hope it helps someone because I didn't find this info anywhere online and it was a lot of trial and error.

Use `ls -l` to list the current owner of folders in the current working directory, so you can compare them.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this turned out to be somewhat complicated. I had provisioned my server using Ansible, which has a task to copy the Nginx conf. After provisioning the server, I changed RAILS_MASTER_KEY.

It turns out that my Ansible task does not re-write the Nginx conf if it already exists on the server (the file is not compared, I guess). So although I updated RAILS_MASTER_KEY in my Ansible playbook (and it was even getting copied across to the server's environment variables!), it was not accessible to Rails through passenger because it does not pass on the user's environment variables.

Whew!

To fix this (and create a snowflake server in the process...) I manually logged into the server and updated RAILS_MASTER_KEY to my new value in the Nginx passenger_env_var.